# problem in toggle function of jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have a section in my website that needs to be toggled by clicking on the title .

now i wrote this code to toggle when clicking on title

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".toggle_container").hide();
$("h4.trigger").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
});
});
```

html part :

```
<h4 class="trigger"><a href="javascript:void(0)">'.$row[title].'</a></h4>
<div class="toggle_container">
 <div class="block">
  '.$row[text].'
 </div>
</div>
```

now with these codes everything goes fine , untill it just opens every title clicked **and not closes opened ones** ;

**1st**

now i have to change this script in a way that when i click on a title to toggle first check opened ones and close those first

**2nd**

and the other thing im wondering is how to make the first title to be opened already , 
when the page loaded the first title to be opened

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm the only one who can't see any PHP code here?

Comment: just an FYI $("h4.trigger").click(function(){ 
  $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow"); 
}); 
 is better written as
$("h4.trigger").click().toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");

Comment: @Mark - That code has a **completely** different meaning. His code is an event handler for the `click` event, yours *triggers* the `click` event and performs actions on each `h4.trigger`, not at all what he's after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was hoping one of the other answers would update and fix this, but both of them never toggle, they always *show*, here's how to toggle and hide the others like you want:

```
$(function(){
  $(".toggle_container:gt(0)").hide();
  $("h4.trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow")
           .siblings(".toggle_container").slideUp();
  });
});
```

[You can try out a demo here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/4a5pr/1/), it shows the first on load, and correctly toggles the rest.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it I guess

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".toggle_container").hide();
 $(".toggle_container:first").show();
  $("h4.trigger").click(function(){
    $(".toggle_container").hide();
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: This would always show the next `.toggle_container` on click, since you're hiding *all* of them on each click, making the toggle state/`.active` class an invalid representation of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Html

```
<h4 class="trigger"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Title1</a></h4>
<div class="toggle_container">
 <div class="block">
  Test
 </div>
</div>
<h4 class="trigger"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Title2</a></h4>
<div class="toggle_container">
 <div class="block">
  Test
 </div>
</div>
<h4 class="trigger"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Title2</a></h4>
<div class="toggle_container">
 <div class="block">
  Test
 </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle_container:gt(0)").hide();
    $("h4.trigger").click(function(){
    $(".toggle_container:visible").slideUp('slow');
  $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
});
});
```

You can check working demo at http://www.jsfiddle.net/XnV69/3/

Comment: This suffers from the same problem as the other answer...it'll always show, never toggle :) Should be something like this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/XnV69/4/